# Why is a real manifold (used in GR) defined in the way it is?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632892/) question one can read, in defining a real manifold $M$, the following condition must hold:

> $(1)$ Each $p\in M$ lies in at least one $O_\alpha$, i.e. $\{O_\alpha\}$ cover $M$.
>
> $(2)$ For each $\alpha$, there is a one-to-one, onto map $\psi_\alpha: O_\alpha\to U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> ($3$)If any two sets $O_\alpha$ and $O_\beta$ overlap, $O_\alpha\bigcap O_\beta\neq \emptyset$, we can consider the map $\psi_\beta\circ\psi_\alpha^{-1}$ which takes points in $\psi_\alpha[O_\alpha\bigcap O_\beta]\subset U_\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to points in  $\psi_\beta[O_\alpha\bigcap O_\beta]\subset U_\beta$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We require these subsets to be open and this map to be $C^\infty$.

The sets $\{O_\alpha\}$ are open subsets of a continuous collection of (non-equidistant) points which are represented by a column (or row) of $n$ real numbers. The intersection of two open subsets, $O_\alpha\bigcap O_\beta\neq \emptyset$, is open too.

Condition $(3)$ implies that different $\psi_\alpha$'s acting on the same open subset transform this subset into different subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. That's clear. It is required that these different subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are open. The images of open sets can be open or closed tough.

Why is it so important, in stating the conditions for a collection of real points to form a real manifold, that all subsets, {$O_\alpha$}, {$U_\alpha$}, {$\psi_\alpha[O_\alpha\bigcap O_\beta]\subset U_\alpha$}, and {$\psi_\beta[O_\alpha\bigcap O_\beta]\subset U_\beta$}, are open? (Doesn't, by the way, condition $(2)$ imply condition $(3)$?)

General relativity requires the existence of real (curved) manifolds. What's so important about the condition that the different subsets should be open? If you use a manifold without this condition (so instead of using open subsets in the definition of the real manifold above you use closed subsets), will this give another general relativity? Isn't the same structure of a real manifold obtained if the subsets are closed? Does the metric (associated with the $\psi_\alpha$'s) become discontinuous in that case? Or what?

Comment: Where in what you quote does it say anything about closed sets?

Comment: @jacob1729  Doesn't [...] mean that the set is closed?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder The [...] here looks like it's just a grouping symbol. In the original question, (2) implies that the sets $O_\alpha$ are open.  The intersection of open sets is also open.  The condition (3) is about the images of those open sets.  For arbitrary functions the image wouldn't have to be open, but this condition (3) places a restriction on the functions.

Comment: @Brick I replaced the closed subsets by open subsets.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder do you agree that the transition/overlap maps should be 1-1? If so, then continuity would imply that they are homeomorphisms with continuous inverses...

Comment: @TLDR But why does that imply that the target sets are open? The same of what you've written applies if the union set is open and the target set is closed...Or does including the endpoints of a set imply discontinuity?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder it turns out that open sets in some ways have vastly more structure than closed sets: in particular every point of an open set has an open neighborhood, but there isn't always a similarly graceful way to characterize closed sets.

Comment: @TLDR Si it's because of open sets that GR can be formulated (as these open sets are involved in real manifolds, which are used in GR)?

Comment: Well, you could start with that, but eventually you'll need to take the role of the metric or causal structure into account, which may turn out to be a key player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The images of open sets can be open or closed tough.

Not under homeomorphisms.  The image $\psi(O)$ of an open set $O$ under a homeomorphism $\psi$ is also open.  One can see this immediately by noting that $\psi(O)$ is the preimage of $O$ under the map $\psi^{-1}$, and since $\psi^{-1}$ is continuous, $O$ must be open.

Of course, open and closed are not mutually exclusive options, so the $\psi(O)$ might be closed as well, provided that it is *also* open.

> If you use a manifold without this condition (so instead of using open subsets in the definition of the real manifold above you use closed subsets), will this give another general relativity?

No, it would give a nonsensical definition of a manifold - or at least a definition which doesn't capture our motivating desire to construct spaces which look like patches of $\mathbb R^n$ if you zoom in closely enough.

Consider $\mathbb R^3$ as a manifold with the standard topology of open sets defined in terms of open balls.  Consider the origin $p=(0,0,0)$.

- The singleton set $\{p\}$ is a closed set containing $p$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^0$
- The line segment $U_1 = \{ (x,0,0) \ | \ x\in [-1,1]\}$ is a closed set containing $p$ which is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^1$.
- The closed disk $U_2 = \{ (x,y,0) \ | \ x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ is a closed set containing $p$ which is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.
- The closed ball $U_3 = \{ (x,y,z) \ | \ x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1\}$ is a closed set containing $p$ which is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

So you see, talking about *closed* sets doesn't give us what we want.  If we require an *open* neighborhood to be homeomorphic to some $\mathbb R^n$, then it's not hard to see that the only possibility is $n=3$.

> Doesn't, by the way, condition (2) imply condition (3)?

No.  You can have two different charts such that the chart transition map isn't smooth.  Consider the manifold $\mathcal M=\mathbb R$ and the charts $\psi_1:x\in \mathcal M \mapsto  x$ and $\psi_2: x\in \mathcal M \mapsto x^3$.  Both of those are perfectly viable charts, but the transition map $\psi_1 \circ \psi_2^{-1} : x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Very enlightening! Thanks. Especially, "No. It would give a nonsensical definition of a manifold" (which was somehow on the back of my mind). But also the rest of the answer is great!.